# Xcode wake ios app on command ( like push not.)?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there a way to wake up or start ios app from nothing or from background  using something like push notification?  Any sort of info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds exactly like push notifications... How does APNs not address this problem? [Here's a link to Apple's notification docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can set push notification to start your inactive app by clicking on the notification.

You can register Local or Remote notification as per your requirement for your app.

There are specific function in *Objective C* as well as *Swift* to register Local/Remote push notification. The function must be called at the launch time. So it should be written on 
`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method on App Delegate class in case of swift.

In this method to register to receive remote push notifications you have to call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` method via Apple Push Service.

You can set types of the notification... So over all code in Swift will be like that,

```
var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
application.registerForRemoteNotifications();
```

If registration succeeds, the app calls `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)` method and passes it a device token.

Handling Remote Notifications ( This app delegate methods is used to handle remote notification ) :

```
    application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)
    application(_:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:)
    application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
    application(_:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:)
    application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

To register to receive Local push notifications you have to call `application.registerForUserNotifications()` method.

Handling Local Notifications( This app delegate methods is used to handle local notification ) :

```
application(_:didReceiveLocalNotification:)
application(_:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try this out. Do you know if app ( if in bacground or not running at all)  can start background  download  when it  recieves push  Notification.

Comment: Yes it is possible via *Interactive Push Notification*. You can perform a task from notification without open the  App.